# How do I make a window bigger than my screen?

Tags: resolution, window

I want to resize my web browser to be a higher resolution than my screen.

I remember being able to do this in Windows 95 by setting the desktop resolution higher than the monitor resolution. How can I do it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer describes actually how to increase the whole desktop resolution beyond physical resolution and not only a specific window:

*Panning viewport*

*If you want to have a panning viewport, i.e., a virtual screen that's bigger than your physical screen that moves when you move the mouse to the edge ("zoomed in" view) specify the desired physical resolution with --mode and the virtual screen size with --fb and panning area (typically same as virtual screen size) with --panning. For example,*

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --rate 60 --mode 800x600 --fb 1280x1024 --panning 1280x1024*
```

on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

HTH

Answer (score -1):

Try "**sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager**" ...that should get you compiz

[image: Watch Out the highlighted area in the image]

After you installed it open the compiz and you will be shown up with this window 
Go to the **Accessibility->Magnifier** and you can set your shortcut to make it work

[image: Compiz window manager]

Comment: Are there any side effects to doing this that I should know about? Also, the Ubuntu instructions on the page you linked to are for Ubuntu 7.10. Do you think I should follow those?